# Why I get ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to ..?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I got this error:

```
ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to gsMedicApp.Pages.Ricoverato.
```

This is my code

```
 public class Ricoverato
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nosologico { get; set; }
        public string codMedicoAccettante { get; set; }
        public string medicoAccettante { get; set; }
        public object dataRicovero { get; set; }
        public object oraRicovero { get; set; }
        public string cognome { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string specialita { get; set; }
        public string camera { get; set; }
        public string piano { get; set; }
        public string stato { get; set; }
        public object dataDimissione { get; set; }
        public object oraDimissione { get; set; }
        public string tipoRicovero { get; set; }
        public string nomeConvenzione { get; set; }
    }

    public class HospitalizedModel : PageModel
    {
        string MedicID = "TEST123";
        string gsMedicWebApiURL = "https://localhost:7219/api";

        public void OnGet()
        {
           
                        
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(gsMedicWebApiURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/hospitalized?MedicID=" + MedicID).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ricoverato>(jsonResult);
               
            }
            else
            {
                //Something has gone wrong, handle it here
            }

        }
    }
```

This is my Json return:

```
[{"id":1,"nosologico":"2022/12847","codMedicoAccettante":"JONDOE","medicoAccettante":"Jon doe","dataRicovero":"2022-11-04T00:00:00","oraRicovero":"11:02:00","cognome":"XXXZZZZ","nome":"Franco","specialita":"Chirurgia","camera":"202","piano":"2°","stato":"In corso","dataDimissione":null,"oraDimissione":null,"tipoRicovero":"Solvente","nomeConvenzione":"Solvente"},{"id":2,"nosologico":"2022/12484","codMedicoAccettante":"JONDOE","medicoAccettante":"Jon doe","dataRicovero":"2022-11-02T00:00:00","oraRicovero":"11:20:00","cognome":"YUYUYU","nome":"Antonio","specialita":"Chirurgia","camera":"204","piano":"2°","stato":"In corso","dataDimissione":null,"oraDimissione":null,"tipoRicovero":"SSN","nomeConvenzione":"SSN"},{"id":3,"nosologico":"2022/12831","codMedicoAccettante":"JONDOE","medicoAccettante":"Jon doe","dataRicovero":"2022-11-03T00:00:00","oraRicovero":"08:55:00","cognome":"ASASAS","nome":"Giulio","specialita":"Chirurgia","camera":"203","piano":"2°","stato":"In dimissione","dataDimissione":null,"oraDimissione":null,"tipoRicovero":"Solvente","nomeConvenzione":"Solvente"}]
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

UPDATE: jsonresults contain this

Could be lot of \\ the problem ?

Comment: Your JSON doesn't represent a single object, it represents a JSON array. Try using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ricoverato>>`.

Comment: Changin to var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ricoverato>>(jsonResult);

I got: ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[gsMedicApp.Pages.Ricoverato].

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger that `jsonResult` is *actually* what you've shown? I suspect it's not. (If it is, you should be able to provide a [mcve] as a console application with hard-coded JSON.)

Comment: I noticed jsonresult contains lot of \ ....

Comment: Does it start with `"` by any chance? If so, that's a JSON string, *not* the JSON result you showed. (Fundamentally, you won't get the error you're describing with the JSON you showed.)

Comment: @stighy "I noticed jsonresult contains lot of \ ...." I can not see even the one. Pls show us where did you find them?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: problem was this line

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

After removing that, my json is correctly acquired!